# Multi step ajax form submissions (PHP and jQuery)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hope you can give me some insight into the best way to accomplish this since javascript is not my strong point. Let me lay out what I'm trying to accomplish.

I am building a custom application (basically content management). It's being built using PHP (Laminas) MVC architecture so basically, I have a primary application module, and several other modules ie content, users, will have a store at some point. Now, each of these modules will expose its own admin areas for things like content creation, setting management, etc. I already have all of that built and working and is not the problem. However, I want to load only this route /admin which will load the correct layout and related script files, etc, have that done and working. This loads the admin overview and provides the admin landing page for a lack of a better explanation.
Now, this is where it gets tricky, well tricky for me, and limited experience with javaScript. The drop-down menu has event listeners bound to it so that when clicked it loads all of the modules "view" files into the layout into a div#workSpace. Which works. I can also ajax in forms (as the response of the controller's action) and attach listeners on the submit event for those forms, however, when the next form in the process enters the DOM I lose the listener (second step of form submission). The code comments below add a little more information.
I am trying to accomplish having all forms that are ajax into the workSpace div, regardless of how many steps (submissions) are required to still be targeted by the javaScript so as to handle them via ajax. What I do not want is to have to keep editing the javaScript over and over and over any time a new module is introduced that has an additional step...

Relevant sections of the code:
layout.phtml (global layout, is disabled on ajax request, of course)

The related jQuery

```js
$(document).on('click', 'nav#sidebar a.nav-link', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let href = $(this).parent().attr("data-href");
    /**
     * Going home or logging out?
     * All other menu entries are handled within the dashboard workspace
     */
    if(href === "/" || href === "/user/logout") {
        $(location).attr('href', href);
    }
    /**
     * if this is not undefined then we have work to do as it will
     * update the work area inside the div#workSpace which
     * is basically the work area for the dashboard 
     * */ 
    if( typeof href !== "undefined") {
        /**
         * This ajax call loads the calls from the main sidebar menu
         * the .done function parses that data and attaches listeners 
         * to any forms that are ajaxed into the DOM
         * prevents default submission and handles the posting 
         * via ajax
         */
        $.ajax({
            url:href,
            dataType: "html",
        }).done(function(response) {
            /**
             * this call to .html() updates the DOM by replacing the contents
             * of div#workSpace with the response of the ajax 
             * request
             * */ 
            $('div#workSpace').html(response);
            /**
             * Second Ajax request
             * Step One in form submission
             */
            $('div#workSpace > form').on("submit", function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                let location = $(this).attr("action");
                let postData = $(this).serialize();
                let formMethod = $(this).attr("method");
                let request = $.ajax({
                    // handle all of the form submissions based on form action and the data
                    url: location,
                    method: formMethod,
                    data: postData,
                });
                request.done(function(response){
                    $('div#workSpace').html(response);
                    /**
                     * Will be step two of form submission
                     * Form loads but is not handled via ajax
                     *  
                     * I could target the incoming form here, but
                     * what will then happen if another module has
                     * a process that has more than a two-step form submission??
                     */
                });
                request.fail(function(){
                    alert("Processing failed!!")
                });
            });
        });
    } 
});
```

```html
<div id="workSpace" class="content-wrapper">
   <?=$this->content?>
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure the javascript part is not affected / overwritten in any way when you execute any ajax call.

Comment: Its not, the javaScript is loaded only once via the dashboard.phtml layout file. The only incoming is the form itself via the action view file. The ajax call that reloads that is using .html() to insert the response which means its the same form coming back, just with a modified fieldset. Step two will be to handle the image uploading.

Comment: I solved this. By attaching higher in the DOM and using delegated events... I attached to the workSpace div. For those new to jQuery, and javaScript in particular I think its important to understand that you do not have bind to a form to listen to the submit event. Which is very very different to some other languages because of the nature of how the event propagates from inner to outer. I know this seems elementary for some, but for those that are very very new... I think its important to make the distinction.